# How to run 2 python scripts parallely based on priority?

Tags: gpio, web-server, web-interface

I am trying to run script1 which detects an object and actuates an output and another script (script2) for establishing connection using http to actuate the same output through web.

I want to run both the scripts parallely but when someone tries to click a button in the webpage run by script2, script 1 should stop running and script2 should actuate the output once and return to script1.

HERE IS THE CODE FOR SCRIPT 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from time import sleep
ir1=11
ir2=13
r1=16
r2=18
l=40
host_name = '192.168.41.80'  # IP Address of Raspberry Pi
host_port = 8000


def setupGPIO():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)

    GPIO.setup(ir1,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(ir2,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(r1,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(r2,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(l,GPIO.IN)

def getTemperature():
    temp = os.popen("/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp").read()
    return temp


class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def _redirect(self, path):
        self.send_response(303)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.send_header('Location', path)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        html = '''
           <html>
           <body 
            style="width:960px; margin: 20px auto;">
           <h1>Welcome to AMC</h1>
           <form action="/" method="POST">
               Press the button to open the gate :
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OPEN">
           </form>
           </body>
           </html>
        '''
        temp = getTemperature()
        self.do_HEAD()
        self.wfile.write(html.format(temp[5:]).encode("utf-8"))

    def do_POST(self):

        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length).decode("utf-8")
        post_data = post_data.split("=")[1]


        if post_data == 'OPEN':
            cn=0
            while cn<1:
                new1=GPIO.input(ir1)
                new2=GPIO.input(ir2)
                l1=GPIO.input(l)
                GPIO.output(r1,GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.output(r2,GPIO.HIGH)
                if(new1==0 ):
                    GPIO.output(r1,GPIO.HIGH)
                    GPIO.output(r2,GPIO.HIGH)
                    sleep(5)
                    while True:
                        l1=GPIO.input(l)
                        new2=GPIO.input(ir2)
                        GPIO.output(r1,GPIO.HIGH)
                        GPIO.output(r2,GPIO.LOW)
                        if(new2==0 or l1==0):
                            GPIO.output(r1,GPIO.LOW)
                            GPIO.output(r2,GPIO.LOW)
                            cn=cn+1
                            sleep(3)
                            break
                else:
                    continue
        else:
            GPIO.output(r1, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(r2, GPIO.LOW)

        print("LED is {}".format(post_data))
        self._redirect('/')  # Redirect back to the root url


# # # # # Main # # # # #

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = HTTPServer((host_name, host_port), MyServer)
    print("Server Starts - %s:%s" % (host_name, host_port))

    try:
        http_server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        http_server.server_close()
```

Iam new to handling web pages and web servers any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)
Rather than asking about your problem (which is not Pi specific) you are asking about your assumed solution.

Comment: I don't have the solution to the asked question I have mentioned that I have run 2 different scripts which works fine individually. I want to find a way to run both the scripts parallely based on priority. And I have not assumed any solution and open for help which can solve the above problem in any way.

Comment: You have assumed you need to run 2 scripts.

Comment: Why don't you merge both scripts and use multi-tasking? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=221505

Comment: I'll try the same and update the results